Counting columns with Conditional Formatting
I am trying to Evaluate an ISNA(VLOOKUP(...)) formula.  When the ISNA() returns TRUE, the Evaluate works.   When the ISNA() returns FALSE, the code throws a type-mismatch error 13
The VLOOKUPs are the same as some conditional formatting I have.  I'm trying to count cells in columns where conditional formatting is involved.
G6 and G9 referenced in the code are numbers from a column of item numbers.
Sub CF_FAILS()

Dim cellValue As String
Dim cellCount As Long
Dim result As Boolean

'#1 cellValue Returns TRUE AND WORKS

    cellValue = "=ISNA(VLOOKUP($G6,API_RESPONSE,RCI.Item_Lookup,0))"
    result = Application.Evaluate(cellValue)
    If (result) Then
        cellCount = cellCount + 1
    End If

    ActiveSheet.range("A20").Value = result
    
'#2 cellValue Returns FALSE AND FAILS with a TYPE-MISMATCH error
    
    cellValue = "=ISNA(VLOOKUP($G9,API_RESPONSE,RCI.Item_Lookup,0))"
    result = Application.Evaluate(cellValue)  '<== FAILS HERE WITH TYPE-MISMATCH ERROR 13'

    If (result) Then
        cellCount = cellCount + 1
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.range("A21").Value = result
    
End Sub


Application.Evaluate will evaluate the formula in the context of whatever happens to be the Activesheet, which might not always be the sheet you expect.  Better to use a specific sheet reference and the Worksheet.Evaluate  form.

What is the value in the returned cell in the case that's throwing the error?

IMO, this is a better pattern: Application.IsError(Application.VLookup(Range("$G9").Value, Range("API_RESPONSE"), RCI.Item_Lookup, False))

Why don't you just count the columns with conditional formatting using VBA?

I added the VBA code itself--not a pic.  @TinMan, it's not about counting the columns with CF, it's about counting individual cells within a column where the CF was applied.  Also, I like your 'better pattern', and will use it.

@Tim Williams, when I hover over the variable sometimes it doesn't show a value.  Don't understand why.   Originally, that's how I knew it was a type-mismatch error.

If you want to know what type of thing is being returned from Evaluate you can declare result as a variant and then check its type using TypeName(result)

Thank you, @Tim Williams.  I ultimately did find the TypeName() which helped me immensely to discover the issue.  I solved my problem.  I was correct in my wonder, if a failed Evaluate returned a value a different data type on a FALSE.  It does.   When my Evaluate failed, it returned a Variant data type instead of the expected Boolean.  I will post my answer soon.   I appreciate all your help.  It put me on the right path.

Please everybody, vote to reopen this question and I'll post my successful solution.

You're only missing one reopen vote, but if that doesn't arrive then you can always still edit your question and add the solution....

Thank you again.  I'll be back. I'm fleshing out the full solution and not the abbreviated POC.

Here's a simple POC where I was able to tally cells with conditional formatting applied. I Evaluated the formula used in the actual CF.  Failed Evaluations do not return boolean, they return a variant with the error message.  So, I typed 'result' as variant and do the VarType() check.
The RCI prefix is my named column index.  RCI stands for (R)esponse (C)olumn (I)ndex.  In this example it's column 1 of the API-RESPONSE table.
Sub Applied_CF_Counter()

Dim cf_formula As String
Dim cellCount As Long
Dim result As Variant
   
'#1 cf_formula counter

    cellCount = 0

    cf_formula = "=ISNA(VLOOKUP($G6,API_RESPONSE,RCI.Item_Lookup,False))"
    result = Application.Evaluate(cf_formula)
    
    If (VarType(result) = vbBoolean) Then
        If (result) Then
             appliedCount = appliedCount + 1   'count cell if CF formula is True (i.e. applied)
        End If
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.range("A19").Value = cellCount  
    ActiveSheet.range("A20").Value = result     ' Show True or False in a cell for visual validation.
    
End Sub

Now I've got to surround it with loops to roll through cells in each column of the table.  Each column is its own range also. I welcome any better solution but this works as a POC can-do.
EDIT
Here is a screenshot of what I was trying to create. It works well for me.  I blurred content but you can see the cells with errors (i.e. red).

I am no VBA guru.  I worked this out. I can see refactoring opportunities.  I didn't want to get into loops embedded in loops.  I welcome all suggestions for improvement.
Option Base 1
Sub Main()

    Dim columnHeaders() As String
    Dim formulaNames() As String
    Dim formulas() As String
    Dim appliedCountsByColumn() As Integer
    
    columnHeaders = getColumnHeaders("TEST_CASES")
    formulaNames = getFormulaNames("TCF.Formulas") 'range of my CF formulas (20, one for each column)
    formulas = getFormulas(formulaNames)
    
    appliedCountsByColumn = getAppliedCountsByColumn(columnHeaders, formulas)

    Call updateColumnErrorSummary("ColumnErrorSummary", appliedCountsByColumn)
    Call updateSummary

End Sub
Function getColumnHeaders(rangeName As String)

    Dim headers() As String
    ReDim headers(Range(rangeName).Columns.count)
    
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
    
        headers(i) = Range(rangeName).Cells(1, i)
        
    Next i
    
    getColumnHeaders = headers

End Function
Function getFormulaNames(rangeName As String)

    Dim formulaNames() As String
    ReDim formulaNames(Range(rangeName).Rows.count)
    
    For i = LBound(formulaNames) To UBound(formulaNames)
        
        formulaNames(i) = Range(rangeName).Cells(i, 1)
    
    Next
    
    getFormulaNames = formulaNames

End Function
Function getFormulas(formulaNames As Variant)

    Dim formulas() As String
    ReDim formulas(UBound(formulaNames))
    
    For i = LBound(formulaNames) To UBound(formulaNames)
    
        formulas(i) = Range(formulaNames(i)).formula
        
    Next
    
    getFormulas = formulas
    
End Function
Function getAppliedCountsByColumn(columnHeaders, formulas)

    Dim startingRow As Variant
    Dim formula As String    'CF formula
    Dim relFormula As String 'relative formula
    Dim columnName As Range
    Dim appliedCounts() As Integer
    Dim appliedCount As Integer
    Dim result As Variant
    
    ReDim appliedCounts(UBound(columnHeaders))
    
' I store CF formulas in a range called TCF.Formulas.
' Here I mimic how Conditional Formulas apply formulas to each row in the Applies-To range.
' Am sure it could be written smarter.
    
    For i = LBound(columnHeaders) To UBound(columnHeaders)
    
        appliedCount = 0
        
        startingRow = getStartingRow(formulas(i)) ' custom for my circumstances
        If (startingRow < 0) Then
            appliedCount = startingRow    'Not tested
        End If
        
        If (startingRow > 0) Then
        
            For j = 0 To Range(columnHeaders(i)).Rows.count - 1
                      
                relFormula = Replace(formulas(i), startingRow, LTrim(Str(startingRow + j)))
                result = Application.Evaluate(relFormula)
                
                If (VarType(result) = vbBoolean) Then
                    If (result) Then
                        appliedCount = appliedCount + 1   'count cell if CF formula is True (i.e. applied)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
    
        End If
        
        appliedCounts(i) = appliedCount
     
    Next
    
    getAppliedCountsByColumn = appliedCounts

End Function
Function getStartingRow(formula As Variant)

'get starting row number from the Vlookup part of the formula.

    Dim parms() As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim numPos As Integer
    Dim startingRow As Variant
    
    ReDim parms(20) ' arbitrary redim, formula isn't going to have 20 commas
    
    found = InStr(1, UCase(formula), "VLOOKUP") <> 0 'I like to name conditions
    
    If (found) Then
        
        parms = Split(formula, ",")
        pos = InStrRev(parms(0), "(") + 1
        
        For i = pos To Len(parms(0))
            If (IsNumeric(Mid(parms(0), i, 1))) Then
                numPos = i
                Exit For
             End If
        Next
        
        startingRow = Right(parms(0), Len(parms(0)) - (numPos - 1))
    Else
        
        startingRow = -1
    End If
    
    getStartingRow = startingRow

End Function
Sub updateColumnErrorSummary(columnErrorSummaryRange, columnErrorSummaryArray)

'set and format the "Column Error Summary" range

    For i = LBound(columnErrorSummaryArray) To UBound(columnErrorSummaryArray)
        
        Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i) = columnErrorSummaryArray(i)
        
        If (columnErrorSummaryArray(i) < 0) Then
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221) 'Grey
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  'black
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Size = 14
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = False
        
        ElseIf (columnErrorSummaryArray(i) = 0) Then
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 'None-white
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  'black
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Size = 14
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = False
        
        ElseIf (columnErrorSummaryArray(i) > 0) Then
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)    'white
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Size = 14
            Range(columnErrorSummaryRange).Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = True
        
        End If
        
    Next

    Call vba_borders(columnErrorSummaryRange)
    Call CenterText(columnErrorSummaryRange)

End Sub
Sub updateSummary()

    Range("TC.ColsWithErrors").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
    Range("TC.ColsWithErrors").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
    Range("TC.ColsWithErrors").Font.Bold = True
    Range("TC.ColsWithErrors").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("ColumnErrorSummary"), ">0")
    
    Range("TC.ColsNotTested").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221) 'Grey
    Range("TC.ColsNotTested").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  'black
    Range("TC.ColsNotTested").Font.Bold = True
    Range("TC.ColsNotTested").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("ColumnErrorSummary"), "<0")
    
    Range("TC.TotalErrors").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
    Range("TC.TotalErrors").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
    Range("TC.TotalErrors").Font.Bold = True
    Range("TC.TotalErrors").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("ColumnErrorSummary"), ">0")
    
End Sub
Sub vba_borders(namedRange)

    Dim iRange As Range
    Dim iCells As Range
    Set iRange = Range(namedRange)
    
    For Each iCells In iRange
        If (iCells.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)) Then 'red
            iCells.BorderAround _
                    LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
                    Weight:=xlThin
        End If
    Next iCells
    
End Sub
Sub CenterText(namedRange)
    Range(namedRange).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub


I made the fix... good catch. Apologies.
